# GoogleMaps does not load on page load

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I can't get my map running using the GoogleMaps API V3. The map does not load. I would expect the map to appear in the div with the id `gisMap` but in the Chrome Debugger I get the message:

```
Uncaught InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function
```

**Javascript**

```
var map;

function initMap() {
    // Enabling new cartography and themes
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

    // Setting starting options
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.9078, 32.8252),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    // Getting Map DOM Element
    var mapElement = document.getElementById('gisMap');

    // Creating a map with DOM element
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
}
```

**Bundle.js (excerpt)**

```
(...)
module.exports = Vue;
}).call(this,require('_process'))
},{"_process":1}],3:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

var map;

function initMap() {
    // Enabling new cartography and themes
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

    // Setting starting options
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.9078, 32.8252),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    // Getting Map DOM Element
    var mapElement = document.getElementById('gisMap');

    // Creating a map with DOM element
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
}

},{}],4:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

var Vue = require('vue');

new Vue({});
(...)
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MFServer Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
</head>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MFDispo</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Start</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">GIS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>

    <body id="app">
        <div class="pageWrapper">
            <div id="gisMap"></div>
            <div id="content"></div>
        </div>

        <script src="/js/bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-KXn5puMvxCw+dAYznun+drMdG1IFl3agK0p/pqT9KAo= sha512-2e8qq0ETcfWRI4HJBzQiA3UoyFk6tbNyG+qSaIBZLyW9Xf3sWZHN/lxe9fTh1U45DpPf07yj94KsUHHWe4Yk1A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBDucSpoWkWGH6n05GpjFLorktAzT1CuEc&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

**SCSS**

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
@import "partials/forms";

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.pageWrapper {
  background-color: red;
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#gisMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: I've assumed that your initMap function is in the bundle.js file, am I right?
Are you sure that initMap is visible from the global scope?

Comment: Hi Marcin, yes, it is available. I edited the question and I am showing an excerpt from this file there

Comment: I see that it's wrapped in some module.

Comment: what do you mean? Well, I use browserify with gulp to pack up the js file and import the bundle file at the end.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: remove `map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);`  and change `var mapElement = document.getElementById('gisMap' , mapOptions);`

Comment: Well, the code that you suggested him to change does not even get called...

Comment: @sesc360 have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Make sure that **initMap** function is visible from **the global scope** or the parameter passed as callback to google maps.js is **properly namespaced**.
In your case, the quickest solution will be replacing:

```
function initMap(){
//..
}
```

to:

```
window.initMap = function(){
//...
}
```

or namespace version:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBDucSpoWkWGH6n05GpjFLorktAzT1CuEc&callback=YOUR.NAMESPACE.initMap" async defer></script>
```

**//Edit:**

I see that in your code snippet you use some async module loading (require.js?) and the code in which you create window.initMap function does not get executed unless you call the module that contains this declaration. So you have not fulfilled the first condition that I've mentioned - the initMap must be visible from the global scope before you call google maps.js.

Comment: still no changed result. I used the window.initMap
But unfortunately, the result is unchanged and the map is not visible

Comment: Which one did you use?

Comment: Oh... If I do window.onload instead of window.initMap it works fine

Comment: You have not fulfilled the "must be visible from the global scope" condition. See edited answer.

Comment: The window.init solution now works very well! Thank you!

Comment: same thing i tried but in console error coming "InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function" . how can i fix this (this error occure in IE 10 + only)

Comment: instead of using initMap can i use some other function name like InitializeMap?

Answer (score 11):

Simply make sure that the script element with the initMap function in it comes before the google maps api script element in your HTML.  Also, the async defer attributes included in Google's examples may be causing the problem.  Simply remove those attributes.

```
<script src='/js/script.js'></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURKEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: In my ase map started showing after adding `async defer`don't know how?

Comment: you saved my day!!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
                                    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY&signed_in=true">
                                    initMap()
                                    </script>
                                    <div id="map_canvas" style=""></div>
                                    <body id="loadMap" onload="initializeMap(-79, 43,'')"></body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. 
Solved it by moving:

```
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=-yourkey-=initMap" async defer></script>
```

after:

```
    // Google Map
    function initMap() {
        GoogleMap.initGoogleMap();
    }
```

Hope it will be of any assistance for someone...

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer :)

After a little faffing around. I've determined that the js file with your Google Maps function in should **not** be *async*

So in my case

```
<script async type="text/javascript" src="js/home.js"></script>
```

became

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/home.js"></script>
```

This does not mean that the Google Maps API call can't have *async* and/or *defer* attributes included!

Ie, my call looks like this, and comes before the local **home.js** file

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[APIKEY]&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `async defer` in the end of google maps api like this

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR API KEY HERE&callback=initMap" async defer></script>`

I hope it will work fine.

Comment: See this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033329/defer-attribute-doesnt-work-with-google-maps-api

Comment: Adding a codeblock and a simple reference link to another answer is not an answer in itself and does not really expand the abilities of the person asking the question. ***why*** does `sync defere` work to solve this issue?