# Leverage Browser Caching and Console Warning

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, browser-cache

I made site and now when I'm tesitng this inside google PageSpeedInsights tool I have problem with Leverage Browser Caching for that same script.

This is my script that I'm calling inside HTML file

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDktC0AXgcEZ5p9yN3RKLs_HCi6JKjZUeE&callback=initMap"></script
```

PageSpeedInsights show me this problem

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/…Z5p9yN3RKLs_HCi6JKjZUeE&callback=initMap (30 minuta)
```

Also when I watching errors in the console show me te warning  for that same script. Now I'm thinking that i make something totally wrong.

This is error in console:

Uncaught InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function    js?key=AIzaSyDktC0AXgcEZ5p9yN3RKLs_HCi6JKjZUeE&callback=initMap:95

Does anybody now what is the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Sounds like you've not got an `initMap` function.

Comment: I see that but I can't find solutions for that problem. 

But do you maybe now how to solve this same problem with leverage browser caching

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue was raised on [this github project](https://github.com/ashleyhsia0/breadcrumbs/issues/14), in which they referenced a [stackoverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466718/googlemaps-does-not-load-on-page-load) as a possible solution.

Make sure the `initMap()` is a global scoped function or the parameter passed to the Google Maps JS is properly namespaced.