# initMap is not a function in using google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

```
<html>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
 </script>
<body onload="showMap()">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showMap() {
        console.log('at maps');
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }
                });
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm new to scripting . This is my code to display the map. But it throws an uncaught error "initMap is not a function". Can anyone help ??

Comment: How/where are you [including the Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API)?

Comment: have included with api key.. But still error thrown

Comment: There is no reference to `initMap` in the posted code (so it is very unlikely to exhibit the issue reported in the (current) title of the question).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Rename `showMap` to `initMap`. Google is expecting to call a function named `initMap` because of the `callback=initMap` URL parameter you've passed them when loading in the Maps API.  But you don't have a function with that name, you've only got a function called `showMap`.

Also, by specifying that callback parameter, you don't need to then explicitly call initMap  or showMap yourself.  So remove `onload="initMap()"` from the `<body>` tag.

Also, when you load in the Maps API, you've got a typo in the URL, instead of:

```
jskey=YOUR_API_KEY
```

it should be:

```
js?key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

And finally, you're missing any `<head>` section, which I've added, and I've moved the function into the `<head>` so it should be defined by the time the callback function gets called.

So this should work:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function initMap() {
        console.log('at maps');
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }
                });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still throws error. Uncaught Vb-> message
:
"initMap is not a function"
name
:
"InvalidValueError"

Comment: Try moving your function into the `<head>` too, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Moving the google.map API call

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_CODE&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

after `function initMap()` is defined fixed this problem for me. I guess Javasrcipt runs sequentially so it can't see the initMap() function when it is defined in the google.map callback.

Answer (score 3):

Late late answer but you might want to check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57392852/11858000). The main problem is that you are not putting the `script` after defining the `map`. Code simply is looking for a web element before it's created on the page.

Comment: No. This has nothing to do with that. The API call contains a callback `initMap` and that function doesn't exist. Please remove your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i'm playing too with google maps and i see this error occurs when you open the same file in different tabs of the navigator...

I'm talking about " Uncaught: Vb "

When you reboot your computer this error deseapear so for not reboot you can press '**F12**' and then go to '**Network**' tab ( F5 ), right click over anything then '**clear browser chache**' & '**clear browser cookies**'..

*If the error Uncaught: Vb still press F5 Two or Three times*

**Other reference for this question:**

[GoogleMaps does not load on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466718/googlemaps-does-not-load-on-page-load])

***Anyways your error is thrown cause you don't specify YOUR_API_KEY and the paramater in the URL is not well formatted ( js?key= )***

**Check this:**

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key

Answer (score -1):

To us google maps you have to first include reference to google maps javascript file.

Include this script below your body.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Please also read documentation of google maps. You might need api keys too.

Comment: uncaught Vb  "initMap is not a function"

Answer (score -2):

Put this script tag in you head section.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Make sure you replace YOUR_API_KEY label with your key which you can get from here..

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Comment: That is not the answer to this problem as this problem relates to initMap