# Google Maps error on WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps

Need your help. I have the error on my WordPress site. Google Maps shows this errors:

```
Jb {message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Jb (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…xALxizYJSGZA470&callback=initMap&ver=4.9.5:157:51"}
```

And this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null
```

In my code.js I have this code:

```
(function ($) {

    ...

    function initMap(officeLocation, pathMap) {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(pathMap), {
            zoom: 15,
            center: officeLocation
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: officeLocation,
            map: map
        });
    }

    showOnKyivMap.on('click', function() {
        mapCover.fadeIn(500);
        initMap(kyivOffice, mapFooter);
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        initMap(kyivOffice, mapKyivContacts);
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Google Map script is connected in functions.php

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'google-maps', "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAN-c6nn0xMNJB_2SfGxALxizYJSGZA470&callback=initMap", array("code-js"), '', true);
```

So what do I do wrong?

Comment: Does it run in the `<head>`?

Comment: See a few more solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466718/googlemaps-does-not-load-on-page-load

Comment: Move the `initMap`-function to the global scope. If you define a function inside a function, that function will only be accessible from within that function.

Comment: Some response would be nice.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! Sorry for such a late answer. Moving to global scope has really solved the problem

Comment: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null - only this error has left

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using function to create google map, you can use `<iframe>` for showing google map. For using `<iframe>` properly use you can visit to below link:
 https://en.support.wordpress.com/google-maps/