# cannot create map route with auto complete search functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

In my form autocomplete search input and Map route is not working togetherly.

autocomplete search is working when I add async defer in script

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&key=*key*&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        >
        </script>
```

and Map route is working when I remove async defer in script

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyBNHI4xFw5CzYJSvbotLPu93C81q69ZbZA&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer>
        </script>
```

this is my complete code

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyBNHI4xFw5CzYJSvbotLPu93C81q69ZbZA&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer>
        </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post">
    <div id="locationField">
      <input id="autocomplete" name="txtpickup" placeholder="Enter your address"
             onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" style="width:20em;"></input>
             <br/>
             <br/>
    <input id="autocomplete1" name="txtdrop" placeholder="Enter your address"
    onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" style="width:20em;"></input>
              <br/>
             <br/>

     <input id="checkprice" type="submit" value="checkprice" name="checkprice" style="width:20em;"></input>

    </div>
<form>


  <?php

  if (isset($_POST['checkprice']))
  {
      $pickupaddress = $_POST['txtpickup'];
      $dropaddress = $_POST['txtdrop'];


$geo = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.urlencode($pickupaddress).'&sensor=false');

$geo = json_decode($geo, true);

if ($geo['status'] == 'OK') {

  $latitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
  $longitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];


}

//-------   drop  coordnates -----------


  $geo1 = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.urlencode($dropaddress).'&sensor=false');

$geo1 = json_decode($geo1, true);

if ($geo1['status'] == 'OK') {

  $latitude1 = $geo1['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
  $longitude1 = $geo1['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];

}


echo '<div><input id="anything" type="button" value="Show Route" onClick="updatePos(\''.str_replace("'", "\\'", $latitude).'\', \''.str_replace("'", "\\'", $longitude).'\', \''.str_replace("'", "\\'", $latitude1).'\', \''.str_replace("'", "\\'", $longitude1).'\');" ></div>';


  }


 // -------- distance   -------------

 function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
    return ($miles * 1.609344);
  } else if ($unit == "N") {
      return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
      }
}


?>




<div id="map_canvas" style="float:left;width:70%;height:400px;"></div>
<ul></ul>
<p id="pMsg"></p>
</body>


<script type="text/javascript">

function updatePos(latitude,longitude,latitude1,longitude1){

ginit(latitude,longitude,latitude1,longitude1);

}



      function initAutocomplete() {


        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
            {types: ['geocode']});

             autocomplete1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            (document.getElementById('autocomplete1')),
            {types: ['geocode']});


      }


      function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
              center: geolocation,
              radius: position.coords.accuracy
            });
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
          });
        }
      }



var directions = {};
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function ginit(latitude,longitude,latitude1,longitude1) {


    var opts = {
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.524268, 13.406290000000013)
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), opts);


    var routes = [{
        label: 'Erkner',
        request: {
            origin: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
            destination: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude1, longitude1),
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        },
        rendering: {
            marker: {
                icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
            },
            draggable: true
        }
    }
];

    var dists = [10000, 5000, 3000, 1000];
    var selects = document.createElement('select');
    list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    for (var d = 0; d < dists.length; ++d) {
        selects.options[selects.options.length] = new Option(dists[d], dists[d], d == 0, d == 0);
    }

    for (var r = 0; r < routes.length; ++r) {
        bounds.extend(routes[r].request.destination);
        bounds.extend(routes[r].request.origin);
        routes[r].rendering.routeId = 'r' + r + new Date().getTime();
        routes[r].rendering.dist = dists[0];
        var select = selects.cloneNode(true);
        select.setAttribute('name', routes[r].rendering.routeId);
        select.onchange = function () {
            directions[this.name].renderer.dist = this.value;
            setMarkers(this.name)
        };
        list.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
        list.lastChild.appendChild(select);
        list.lastChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode(routes[r].label));

        requestRoute(routes[r], map);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}


function setMarkers(ID) {
    var direction = directions[ID],
        renderer = direction.renderer,
        dist = renderer.dist,
        marker = renderer.marker,
        map = renderer.getMap(),
        dirs = direction.renderer.getDirections();
    marker.map = map;

    for (var k in direction.sets) {

        var set = directions[ID].sets[k];
        set.visible = !! (k === dist);

        for (var m = 0; m < set.length; ++m) {

            set[m].setMap((set.visible) ? map : null);
        }
    }
    if (!direction.sets[dist]) {
        if (dirs.routes.length) {
            var route = dirs.routes[0];
            var az = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; ++i) {
                if (route.legs[i].distance) {
                    az += route.legs[i].distance.value;
                }

            }
            dist = Math.max(dist, Math.round(az / 100));
            direction.sets[dist] = gMilestone(route, dist, marker);

        }
    }
}

function requestRoute(route, map) {
    if (!window.gDirSVC) {
        window.gDirSVC = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    }

    var renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(route.rendering);
    var renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(route.rendering);
    renderer.setMap(map);
    renderer.setOptions({
        preserveViewport: true
    })


    google.maps.event.addListener(renderer, 'directions_changed', function () {

        if (directions[this.routeId]) {
            //remove markers
            for (var k in directions[this.routeId].sets) {
                for (var m = 0; m < directions[this.routeId].sets[k].length; ++m) {
                    directions[this.routeId].sets[k][m].setMap(null);
                }
            }
        }

        directions[this.routeId] = {
            renderer: this,
            sets: {}
        };
        setMarkers(this.routeId);

    });

    window.gDirSVC.route(route.request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            renderer.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}

function gMilestone(route, dist, opts) {

    var markers = [],
        geo = google.maps.geometry.spherical,
        path = route.overview_path,
        point = path[0],
        distance = 0,
        leg,
        overflow,
        pos;

    for (var p = 1; p < path.length; ++p) {
        leg = Math.round(geo.computeDistanceBetween(point, path[p]));
        d1 = distance + 0
        distance += leg;
        overflow = dist - (d1 % dist);

        if (distance >= dist && leg >= overflow) {
            if (overflow && leg >= overflow) {
                pos = geo.computeOffset(point, overflow, geo.computeHeading(point, path[p]));
                opts.position = pos;
                markers.push(new google.maps.Marker(opts));
                distance -= dist;
            }

            while (distance >= dist) {
                pos = geo.computeOffset(point, dist + overflow, geo.computeHeading(point, path[p]));
                opts.position = pos;
                markers.push(new google.maps.Marker(opts));
                distance -= dist;
            }
        }
        point = path[p]
    }


    console.log(markers); //alert(markers);

    for (var key in markers) {
        var obj = markers[key];
        console.log(obj);

        if (markers[key].hasOwnProperty("position")) {
            document.getElementById("pMsg").innerHTML += key+":"+markers[key].getPosition().toUrlValue(6) +"<br>";
        }

    }

    return markers;

}



</script>



</html>
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should use the asynchronous version of the API.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033329/defer-attribute-doesnt-work-with-google-maps-api maybe this can help you.

Comment: Maybe docs can help us :) https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Comment: i told autocomplete is not issue , make autocomplete work with google route is issue